# TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable - HTTP 500 POST

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have completed a Python & Flask application and am facing a strange error. I am getting an `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable` error, but all of the code in my Flask route works as expected. I get a 500 error in my Flask log, but all pieces of the code work correctly (goalHorn, goalLights & set_power_state).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
@app.route('/tests/full', methods=['POST'])
def performTestsFull():
print('Full Test Password POSTed - ', request.form['password'])
if request.form['password'] == config.post_test:
    print('Passowrd verified - Testing Lights & Sounds!')

    if Receiver.get_power_state() == 'STANDBY':
        powerFlipped = True
        print('Receiver was off - powerFlipped is', powerFlipped)
        Receiver.set_power_state('ON')
        time.sleep(2)

    LightsSounds.goalHorn('enable')
    LightsSounds.goalLights('enable')

    time.sleep(config.goal_time)
    LightsSounds.goalHorn('disable')
    LightsSounds.goalLights('disable')
    # GPIO.cleanup()

    if powerFlipped is True:
        Receiver.set_power_state('OFF')
        print('Receiver was off - turning it back off now...')

    return True
else:
    print('Incorrect Password - NOT Testing Lights & Sounds!')
    return False
```

This is the HTML template that calls this route -

```
$("#both-test-disabled").bind('click tap', function() {
        promptPW = prompt("Enter password to perform full test...");
        // if(confirm("Goal Horn is disabled - are you sure you want to enable?")) {
        if (promptPW) {
            $.post("/tests/full", { password: promptPW });
        } 
        return false;
    });
```

And finally, this is the getter for Power State in the Flask Route -

```
def get_power_state():
url = 'http://' + denon_ip + status_url
try:
    response = requests.get(url)
    root = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content)
    for value in root.iter('Power'):
        powerState = value[0].text
        # print("Power State - ", powerState)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("Network Exception - ", e)
    powerState = 'N/A'
return powerState
```

Comment: Your indentation look incorrect

Comment: any traceback or full log of error?

Comment: post full traceback pls